# jQuery player brought in by iframe won't auto play but pop out does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a rather strange issue with my jPlayer. I have been using this player for about 2 years now, and it's worked great iframed from my server into a web page elsewhere. Recently I did move the players from GoDaddyto my hosted WHM server. I at least thought they worked properly after but now when you open a page with it the music names n title scrolls fine but no music.

But if you hit the pop out box upper right, a new pop out box appears, and it plays fine and no longer had the little square for the pop out. As an experiment I copied the pop out link back into the iframe and ended up the pop out link box wasn't there and still no music. I tried re-copying the entire player directory again from GoDaddy and had the same experience. Was there maybe a change with Chrome and iframe security?

If I put the link in the original iframe  directly into  the address bar in Chrome it works fine, as does the url that accompanies the pop out.

I'm a baby at best when it comes to this but often I don't hear from my developer for some time and I am trying to learn.

```
<IFRAME src="http://players3.djextreme.net/global/index.php?stream=8004" width="375" scrolling="no" height="350" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I can get to the various codes but this is the start. There are many players back ended into the same player vix XML file but none of that has changed. This also works fine in IE and Firefox.

Comment: What does " There are many players back ended into the same player" mean?

Comment: When I bought the original code it would have been 1 player per client. With the help of my developer He was able to make it where each customer I just make an XML file for and add it to a configs folder.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't function in the Snippet because of strict security but it works in this `<kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/mqQLk7GlWJoD1vGmhH1c/)</kbd>. I'm not sure what you are asking...

```html
<iframe src="http://players3.djextreme.net/global/index.php?stream=8004" width="375" scrolling="no" height="350" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: When the page is initially loaded the music used to play to put it in simple terms but now it does not. I moved this player from godaddy to my own server  and as i said the music will platy through a pop out in chrome and will play in initial pages of IE and firefox just not Chrome. I read there was something with Iframe security and chrome., But this worked until a couple weeks ago when i moved it. AND the player only malfunctions in the initial page with chrome.

Comment: In the example above. The player sows the song titles but is not playing but if you load just http://players3.djextreme.net/global/index.php?stream=8004  into chrome it plays. It USED to play automatically and Still does in IE and firefox. Why isnt it playing initially in chrome?